# what is the difference between later and latter?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

As cited above what is the difference between **later** and **latter**?

**Latter** : occurring or situated nearer to the end of something than to the beginning, the meaning of latter is similar to later only. so please throw the real difference between both of the words.

Comment: Did you look this up in a dictionary? If you did, what remains confusing to you, so that we might be better able to help?

Comment: @medica i have edited the question, or please edit my question.

Comment: If you're still confused, please edit your question to ask about what it is that confuses you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*Latter*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latter) is at the end. Being the second of two persons or things mentioned; near or nearer to the end. It has more to do with *placement*, so to speak. Location, real or figurative.

Between captain and major, the **latter** is the higher rank.
My favorite is the **latter** part of the book.

[*Later*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/later) has more to do with *time*.

She arrived an hour *later* than expected.
Better plant your tomatoes *later* in the Spring than sooner; tomatoes don't do well in the cold.

They are similar, but not interchangeable. You can't say "I'd prefer the later" if asked if you would prefer coffee or tea. You can't say, "Plant them latter in the season."

You *can* say, *in the latter **part** of Spring*, as with the *latter chapters of a book.*

You can say, I'd like some coffee, but **later**, please.

Comment: thanks for mentioning about time in later, that is what i expected.

Comment: @medica +1 for examples of what you *cannot* say, these are helpful.