# Late “latter” last

Tags: word-usage, etymology, adjectives, comparatives

PREMISE: I am not asking about the difference in meaning or usage between *latter* and *later*; it is, therefore, not a duplicate of the older question:
*[what is the difference between later and latter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164073/what-is-the-difference-between-later-and-latter)*

Instead, I would like to understand more about **its history** and why it is rarely used as the comparative adjective of *late*, and, finally, if the superlative *“the most latter”*  ever existed.

According to Wiktionary, *[latter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latter)* is not comparable.

### Latter

> Adjective
> *latter* (not comparable)
>
> Relating to or being the second of two items.
> Near (or nearer) to the end.
> Close (or closer) to the present time.

In fact, “more latter” or “lattermore” are nonexistent as is “most latter” but “lattermost” is cited in all the major dictionaries, *English Oxford Dictionaries* defines it as: *[Nearest to the end, final, last](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lattermost)* although it fails to mention that it is a superlative.

I admit to feeling confused, and I would argue that the following examples are using *latter* as a comparative adjective.

> - I prefer his latter book than his first *(I prefer his second book)*
> - There are more ways of achieving the latter [fame] than the former [great wealth].

It also seems clear that *latter* is an [ungradable adjective](https://www.pearson.pl/fileadmin/poland/english/products/files/sample_files/9780582403833.pdf); it cannot be modified by using *very*, *really*, *quite* or *less* in front nor by using words such as *absolutely* or *completely* and I have never seen the superlative form, “the most latter”.

Additionally, I cannot come up with a single example where the word *latter* is used in a sentence without the definite article or a determiner.

From *[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/latter)*

> ‘the latter half of 1989’
> ‘heart disease dogged his latter years’
> ‘… in the latter stages of the game.’
> ‘…in the latter part of the week than at the beginning of the week.’
> ‘The latter half of my previous letter,…’

I later checked on Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20latter%2Cthis%20latter%2Cmy%20latter%2Cand%20latter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20latter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20latter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20latter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20latter%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20latter%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20latter%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20latter%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20latter%3B%2Cc1) and "the latter" is by far the most common pairing

[image]

Last but not least, I found the following chart that says *latter* is the comparative adjective, until very recently I had never seen nor heard that the adjective *late* was irregular.

[image]

Different charts which include *latter* can be seen on this [site](http://www.keywordlister.com/Y29tcGFyYXRpdmUgYWRqZWN0aXZlcw/) (23/28 image) and [here](https://twitter.com/browncowenglish/status/626430064771600384). I'm tempted to say that the charts are mistaken, but are they?

- Is (or was) *late* an irregular adjective?
- Is *latter* non-comparable as Wiktionary claims it to be?
- Why is *latter* nearly always preceded by the definite article, is this semantically or grammatically significant?

Comment: ***Latter*** is an older term than later, which is probably a later formation or a variant of latter:  “*Old English lætra "slower," comparative of læt "late"* (see late (adj.)). ***Meaning "belonging to a subsequent period" is from c. 1200***. ***Sense of "that has been mentioned second of two or last" is first recorded 1550s.***”

Comment: ***In modern use the more common word is later, which is from mid-15c. and is perhaps a new formation or a variant of this word.*** Latter survives mostly in the phrase the latter, which, with the former is used to avoid repetition (but sometimes incorrectly, when more than two are involved).  https://www.etymonline.com/word/latter

Comment: You could argue that _late_ has both a regular and an irregular declension: _late/later/latest_ and _late/latter/last_. Historically, you’d be correct. Synchronically… arguably correct. You could also argue that _latter_ and _last_ are both indeclinable adjectives that are historically and semantically linked to _late_, but not actual inflections of it. I don’t think there is really any way of saying decisively that one approach is correct and the other incorrect.

Comment: ***There are more ways of achieving the latter [fame] than the former [great wealth]***. Reconsider this sentence. Here both *the latter* and *the former* are nouns, aren't they?

Comment: “Latter" isn't comparable in the same - and vital - way "elder" isn't but “older” is…

Comment: a latter: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+latter%22+-%22latter-day%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks

Answer (score 3):

### "The "obvious" answer

I'm going to attempt a rare answer with no research.

I don't like the phrase *non-comparable* and would argue that it's a poor term for what is meant to describe the distinction of **latter**.

> I prefer his **latter** book over his first

If this means a preference for the second book, it only works if there are only two books.  It does not seem correct or clear to say:

> Out of his first, second, and third books, I prefer the **latter**.

Maybe "latter" in its purest form is a **binary** term, functioning as the opposite of "former."  Neither implies an immediate relationship as with **preceding** or **following**.

Perhaps over time it evolved to mean, simply, "later," and led to words like "lattermost," as a recent development, in meaning and character...

### So what if I had done research?

It turns out, according the *OED*, that the opposite is true.  **Latter** in its earliest uses in English simply meant "later than," or, even better, often "slower," or even just "worse" or "less than [in any sense]."  Hardly a "non-comparable" term, in that it seemed to imply only that anything would be better, faster, or sooner in comparison.

In fact, the distinction between "latter" and "later" seems to have happened a little latter than I thought.

> All examples of later earlier than 1500 have been regarded as showing ***latter*** *adj., adv., and n.*, although it is conceivable that some (especially in senses A. 2a or B. 1) may rather belong as antedatings at **later** *adv., adj., and int.*)

Only first in **c1225**, long before the *OED* has, in the aforementioned quote, determined a distinction between antedatings of "later" and "latter," do we find a citation that fits the assumptions I laid out at the top of my answer.

> That has been mentioned second of two, last of a group of more than two, or at or near the end of a preceding clause or sentence. Frequently opposed to *former*

Comment: For the record, the quip about being "obvious" is a joke aimed at those who close questions for being too "obvious."  I'm not truly making any statement about this question -- I like it.

Comment: Agree that _latter_ doesn't sound right for three or more things (e.g. books) ... it's predominately a binary thing (e.g. "_the latter **half** of  1989_").

Comment: @TripeHound - Not sure I agree with you there. There are two usages of latter: binary as you say (former vs latter), and as a synonym for "later". I wouldn't say "the former half of 1989", so it's not the first. But then I wouldn't say "the latter third of 1989" either... but I would say "the latter months of 1989" meaning the last 3-4 months. I'm not really sure what my conclusion is... other than that the OP has asked a good question and I can't answer it!

Comment: @AndyT Personally, I'd say "_the latter months of 1989_" to mean that last 3-4 months is wrong (it should be "_later_"), although this is probably drifting into a debate over how part of a language _should_ be used, and how it _sometimes is_ used, and – in a "living language" – whether and how much can "common use" alter "correct use".

Comment: Am I to consider late to be an irregular adjective? Why/why not? Could you please provide a little more detail when the OED  says that *latter* meant "slower" or "worse"? Maybe I should point out I don't have a subscription to the OED. It seems that "latter" is a spelling variant of "later", or have I misunderstood that part?

Comment: @Mari-LouA good questions, I can provide more detail on the OED entries and will do so now in an edit to my answer.

Comment: I'm still working on an update to the answer, but have been short on time, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Job 19:25-27, in the King James Version:

> For I know that my redeemer liveth, and that he shall stand at *the latter day* upon the earth: 
>   And though after my skin worms destroy this body, yet in my flesh shall I see God: 
>   Whom I shall see for myself, and mine eyes shall behold, and not another;

This "latter day," and other KJV references to latter days, possibly refer the last days of earth, and are echoed in the formal title of the Mormon church, The Church of Jesus Christ of *Latter-Day* Saints (established 1830).

And it is latter-day saints that provide most of the instances where *latter* is used with the indefinite article ([a latter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20latter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20latter%3B%2Cc0)), e.g.:

*A Latter Day Saint: Being the Story of the Conversion of Ethel Jones* (1884) (this one is fiction, although most are memoirs) and the more intriguing *Confessions of a Latter-day Virgin: A Memoir* (2013).

There are also a number of legal references, such as "a latter law," which seem to be alternative spellings of *later*. "... a former will may be revoked by a latter one," *A Treatise of Equity*, 1805. Although the use of the indefinite article is infrequent, it seems to follow the usual conventions.

Former/latter are often used in formal writing to refer to the first-mentioned and second-mentioned of a pair, as in your fame-fortune duo; but if it's reversed to fortune-fame, then there are more ways to achieve the latter than the former.

late-later-last:  The boy arrive late; his sister was even later; and the mother was the last of the family to arrive.

But the latest guest to arrive is the most recent to arrive, as in "the latest and greatest" or *the latest fashion*. [late, OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/late)

An incomplete answer, unquestionably, but too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Latter* usually has the distinction of being last on a list; "Dick, Jane and Spot played outside, the latter being Jane's pet dog." However, the idiom currently used with it is, **latter-day:** *modern or contemporary, especially when mirroring some person or thing of the past.* Curiously, I could have written that lead in as; "However, the popular *latter-day* usage is in the idiom, **latter-day**." and been correct.

Comment: I'm in agreement with [RaceYouAnytime](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/444274/91730) and [TripeHound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443733/late-latter-last#comment1067553_444274) that a list of three doesn't use "latter". I'm also pretty sure that I only see "latter-day" when talking about the Church of the Latter-day Saints.

Comment: @AndyT Adj.1. **latter-day** - belonging to the present or recent times; "the latter-day problems of our society"
present - temporal sense; intermediate between past and future; [http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latter-day]

Comment: I'm aware of the meaning of latter-day. That doesn't change the frequency with which I hear it or read it, or when I do the context in which it is used.

Comment: @Andy This question was about the use of *late* and *latter*. Not frequency of usage. The reply to my answer is still only your opinion. I made no mention of my own usage of it - the question did not ask about personal usage.